Why is Shift-Ctrl-V bound to Quit Geany - Is it possible to change it?
In many editing environments Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V are bound to Copy/Paste.
In bash Shift-Ctrl-C is bound to copy (marked portions of the terminal) to clipboard and Shift-Ctrl-V is bound to Paste to the prompt.
In LibreOffice, OpenOffice and other applications, Shift-Ctrl-V is bount to some special version of paste, e.g. paste as special (i.e. without as text any formatting information).
I just used Shift-Ctrl-V in Geany and I was surprised that I got bombed out off Geany without any option to save first! I hoped it were something like "paste at the current indentation level". Ok, using shortcuts not really firmly memorized sometimes yields strange effects, but being bombed out off the application came totally unexpected.
I did not even find Shift-Ctrl-V among the shotcuts that can be set or modified for Geany. Does Geany have any non-modifiable shortcuts? Where are the other shortcuts described? Which file stores the shortcuts to be used for Geany?

Shift-Ctrl-V is not defined among the keyboard shortcuts in xfce4-keyboard-settings. I have only two shortcuts there which use Shift.

Another argument against your reasoning: LibreOffice recognizes this key combination as paste special. One might however change this inside this application. Mathematica is another application, which obeys to Shift-Ctrl-V (in this case like Ctrl-V) with pastes, at least, also Mathematica does not quit on Shift-Ctrl-V.

It's likely a conflict with a default system shortcut into Linux.
For advanced programming usage of your computer, a good idea is to remove them all. And start from scratch incrementally when needed.
In very particular if you use another keyboard than a Qwerty.
There are set in different area into xfce4 and similary in other desktop environnements, we could overide in two different places.

First from the "System start menu" => "settings", "keyboard", "keyboard shortcuts."
Inspect and erase them all, and/or, click Add and create a new shortcut with the command echo alone for Shift+Ctrl+V, that will overide any default shortcuts. You can also use another command. In this capture, i had myself a similar issue with Shift+Ctrl+W, resolved like so:


Other shortcuts combos  related to window and desktop actions are located in:
"Settings manager" => "Window manager" => "Keyboard"


For extrem issues, and/or foreign rare keyboards layouts, we have to dive in the X11 KeySym, and configure by keycode using xmodmap. (Hard)
How to map a X11 KeySym to a Unicode character?
